# Alert when inserting duplicate data in dynamic table | Laravel

Tags: laravel, duplicates, alert, tablerow

I want to try to find a solution that it isn't possible to insert same number twice in a table or to turn red in case the number was inserted before.

See also [bureautintdev.nl/question/example1](http://bureautintdev.nl/question/example1.png)

Comment: You could add a unique index in the db and and then catch the exception in laravel...
btw: your link is broken

Comment: Now the link should also work ;-)

Comment: thanks. do you still need help or is Jenos answer sufficient? If that's the case, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Laravels inbuild validator functionality.

```
$validator = Validator::make(array('phonenumber' => 'required|unique:users') );  
// This will query DB for uniqueness of phone number in users table. Change according to your requirement.

//Check for validation
if($validator->fails()) {   

 $messages = $validator->messages();// get the error message.       
   return Redirect::to('inputview')->withErrors($validator);

}

else
{
   //do your actual operation here.
}
```

In the "inputview", check for "phonenumber" error and do decorate your inputbox into red or raise alert.

```
@if ($errors->has('phonenumber')) <p>{{ $errors->first('phonenumber') }}</p> @endif  //show error.
```